# ion-slide not working with ngFor directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ion-slides, ionic5

[EDIT, new info on the bottom of the post]

In my app I have a couple of different pages with a ion-slides element in. They all work correctly except one, and I've managed to follow the trail to the *ngFor directive.

This is the html code of the page:

```
          <ion-slides pager="false" class="mb-0 mr-2 ml-2">
              <ion-slide  *ngFor="let singolo of plafond; let i=index">
                <ion-card class="res1-container">
                  <ion-card-subtitle class="text-center pt-2 pr-1 pl-1">{{singolo.nomeClasse}}</ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-subtitle>Massimale periodo <b>{{singolo.massimaleDisponibilePeriodo|currency: 'EUR'}}</b></ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-content class="res1-container res1-wrapper">
                    <ngx-gauge  [type]="batchGaugeOpts.type"
                              [size]="batchGaugeOpts.size"
                              [value]="(singolo.totaleRimborsatoPeriodo/singolo.massimaleDisponibilePeriodo)*100"
                              [min]="0"
                              [max]="100"
                              [label]="batchGaugeOpts.label"
                              [thick]="batchGaugeOpts.thick"
                              [animate]="false"
                              [thresholds]="thresholdConfig"
                              [append]="batchGaugeOpts.append"
                              [cap]="batchGaugeOpts.cap"
                    >
                    <ngx-gauge-value>
                      {{((singolo.totaleRimborsatoPeriodo/singolo.massimaleDisponibilePeriodo)*100).toFixed(0)}}
                    </ngx-gauge-value>
                    </ngx-gauge>            
                  </ion-card-content>
                  <div class="mt-0 pb-1 text-center" align="center"><span class="t-blue">{{i+1}} di {{plafond.length}}</span></div>
                </ion-card>
              </ion-slide>
          </ion-slides>
```

the typescript code that populates the "plafond" object is:

```
        const userdata = await this.authenticationService.getUser();   
        const plafond = await this.getPlafondData(userdata);

        setTimeout(async() => {
          this.userdata = userdata;
          this.plafond = plafond;
        }, 1500);
```

getPlafondData returns a promise that is correctly resolved, this is the JSON object i get:

```
[{"idClasse":"1","nomeClasse":"Diaria da infortunio","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":"200.00","massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":600},{"idClasse":"2","nomeClasse":"Diaria da malattia","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":400,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":400},{"idClasse":"3","nomeClasse":"Diaria R.S.A.","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":200,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":200},{"idClasse":"4","nomeClasse":"Visite mediche specialistiche","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":100,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":100},{"idClasse":"5","nomeClasse":"Esami clinici, accertamenti diagnostici e trattamenti fisioterapici","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":100,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":100},{"idClasse":"6","nomeClasse":"Trattamenti termali","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":100,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":100},{"idClasse":"7","nomeClasse":"Servizio ambulanze","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":100,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":100},{"idClasse":"8","nomeClasse":"Servizio Taxi Sanitario","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":100,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":100},{"idClasse":"9","nomeClasse":"Sussidio Scuola","periodo":"2020","totaleRimborsatoPeriodo":null,"massimaleDisponibilePerEvento":500,"massimaleDisponibilePeriodo":500}]
```

That I've validate with jsonlint.io . It's valid.
If I don't use the *ngFor directive but create 9 slides using the notation plafond[index], the slides are correctly rendered and usable.

What is really strange is that on another page of the app I've this other slider:

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="convenzionati?.length >0; else nessunrisultato;" pager="false">
  <ion-slide *ngFor='let convenzionato of convenzionati; let i=index' class="mb-5">
    <ion-card class="res1-container ml-1 mr-1 pl-1 pr-1">        
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-row>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-md-3 pl-1 pr-1">
            <div class="res1-wrapper">              
              <h1><span class="t-blue">{{convenzionato.nomeConvenzionato}}</span></h1>
              <p class="spec">{{convenzionato.descrizioneTipoConvenzionato}}</p>
              <div class="address-container mt-4 mb-3">
                <ul>        

                  <li>{{convenzionato.indirizzo}}</li>
                  <li>{{convenzionato.cap}}</li>
                  <li>{{convenzionato.comune}} ({{convenzionato.provincia}})</li>
                  <li><a href="tel://{{convenzionato.telefono}}">{{convenzionato.telefono}}</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:{{convenzionato.email}}">{{convenzionato.email}}</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <p class="spec" *ngIf="authenticationService.isAuthenticated()">{{convenzionato.agevolazioni}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>          
        </ion-row>
            <ion-button class="bcc-button bcc-button-outline" shape="round" (click)="openMapsApp(convenzionato.indirizzo, convenzionato.comune)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i></ion-button>
<!--             <ion-button fill="outline" (click)="openMapsApp(convenzionato.latitudine, convenzionato.longitudine)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i></ion-button> -->            
           <ion-button class="bcc-button bcc-button-outline" shape="round" (click)="launchNav(convenzionato.indirizzo, convenzionato.comune)"><i class="fas fa-directions fa-2x"></i></ion-button>
<!--            <ion-button fill="outline" (click)="launchNav(convenzionato.latitudine, convenzionato.longitudine)"><i class="fas fa-directions fa-2x"></i></ion-button> -->
      </ion-card-content>
    <div class="mt-3 pb-1 text-center" align="center"><span class="t-blue">{{i+1}} di {{convenzionati.length}}</span></div>
    </ion-card>

  </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Which is working flawlessly getting data pretty much in the same way:

```
this.convenzionati = await this.helperService.lookUp(lookUpCriteria);
```

I've been banging my head on this for some days now without being able to find anything obvious.

This is my ionic info output:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.3.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.0
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.0-beta.1
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.0-beta.1

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.11.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

EDIT
Ok this is even stranger than I thought.
If I put mode="xxx" in the ion-slides definition, it works.. inverted.
If I put `<ion-slides mode="ios">`, it work on **android** devices but not on iPhone. Viceversa, if i put `<ion-slides mode="md">` it works on **iPhone** and not on android. This is **really** weird.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: this.convenzionati = await this.helperService.lookUp(lookUpCriteria); Can you console the value which are getting fro this.convenzionati.

Comment: No error, that's the point. It just do not slide. Like it loaded only the first slide. Which I'm sure is not, beacuse the index is exactly the length of the array.
this.convenzionati is the method that "works" and it's the same format as the non working one.
Can't paste here because it's too long, but it also get validated on jsonlint.io

Comment: can you show the declaration of convenzionati ?

Comment: both "convenzionati" and "plafond" are declared as "any" at the moment.